# Filter ruby warnings

Tags: ruby, warnings

I want to create a gem to filter warnings in Ruby, and I'd like to do this for "syntax" and "runtime" warnings. I am struggling to work out how its possible to filter the syntax level warnings (or if this possible)

For example, if I run the following script

```
# myscript.rb
@blah
```

with `ruby -w myscript.rb`

```
myscript.rb:1: warning: possibly useless use of a variable in void context
myscript.rb:1: warning: instance variable @blah not initialized
```

Now, imagine this is part of a larger project. I would like to filter out any warnings from myscript. How would I go about doing this? Runtime errors would be easy to filter using silence_warnings style code from ActiveSupport https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3be9a34e78835a8dafc3438f60afb412613773b9/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb

But I don't know how (or if it's possible) to hook into Rubys syntax level warnings, as it seems to be they'd be run before you have the chance to monkey patch anything. All I can think of is to wrap the ruby script in another process which will filter all the warnings. For example:

`myfilterprogram ruby -w myscript.rb` which would then catch anything printed to STDERR and filter accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be able to monkey patch before the main file is read, but you can make your main file call subfiles after doing monkeypatching.

**myruby** (executable)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

module Kernel
  def warn *args
    args # => captured warnings
  end
end

load ARGV[0]
```

Usage is:

```
myruby foo.rb
```

Comment: That's a good idea.. what I want to do ideally is to be running the test suite for an app, (e.g `bundle exec rake`) so I'll have to see if I can get your excellent suggesting to work within those bounds. I guess if there's a way to programmatically call rspec to start the test suite then it'll be all good.  I'll mark this as correct for now in the meantime!  Thanks :)